# is the real part of a holomorphic function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

Say we have some entire function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Does this guarantee that the function $Re(f)$ will also be entire?

Comment: It will be entire iff $f$ is constant.

Comment: Ah. Does this come from Cauchy Riemann equations or something different?

Comment: Yes, it exactly follows from Cauchy Riemann equations. If $f=u+iv$ is defined in an open connected domain and $v$ is constant then the partial derivatives of $v$ are zero everywhere. By Cauchy Riemann we conclude that the partial derivatives of $u$ are zero as well. So $f$ is constant.

Comment: Could you explain why we require that v is constant for u to be holomorphic?

Comment: The real part of $f$ has $0$ imaginary part.  Apply C-R to $\Re(f)$

Comment: We don't. But $u$ is a function which only returns real number. So the imaginary part of $u$ (not of $f$, don't get confused) is constant, it is always zero. So $u$ being holomorphic implies that $u$ is constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only entire holomorphic functions whose imaginary parts are constant are the constant functions. So $\operatorname{Re}(f)$ is holomorphic if and only if it is constant (which implies that $f$ itself is constant).

Comment: I follow the first line but I don't understand why Re(f) being holomorphic requires that Im(f) is constant, could you explain?

Comment: $Im(f)$ is not necessary constant. But $Im(Re(f))$ is constant because $Re(f)$ is always a real number. This is why $Re(f)$ being holomorphic implies that it is constant.

Comment: ahhh of course. thanks for the explanation.

Comment: But yes, after we found out that $Re(f)$ is constant then since $f$ is holomorphic with constant real part we conclude that $f$ is constant. So in the end $Im(f)$ is constant as well. But we conclude that only after we proved $Re(f)$ is constant.

Answer (score 6):

If $\mathfrak{R}(f)$ is entire, then $\exp(i\mathfrak{R}(f))$ is also entire. But $|\exp(i \mathfrak{R}(f))| \leq 1$, so $\exp(i\mathfrak{R}(f))$ is constant (Liouville's theorem) and thus so is $\mathfrak{R}(f)$. Hence, $f$ has constant real part, and the C-R equations get you that $f$ has constant imaginary part as well.